# Guidelines regarding design and conception of Inspire geoportal for Public Administration

Tags: geoportal

I am in the process of designing the conception of a geoportal for a local authority which must fulfill the INSPIRE guidelines.

Can anyone offer any information regarding the design and set-up phase of this? Is doesn´t necessarily have to be a technical analysis or overview, but rather a guide to which steps are necessary in order to do the following:

1. Create Data inventory
2. Assess and Understand user needs
3. Interface design...etc.etc

From the conceptual side, it would be usefull to have a list of points which should not be overlooked when designing the concept for a geoportal.

Thanks for any advice,

Robert